# Unity API Offline Search in VSCode

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio I could set offline (or online) help for methods:
Tools -> External Tools… -> Add

```
Title:
Unity API Offline Search
Command:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
Arguments:
"file:///C:/Program%20Files/Unity%20Hub/Documentation/en/ScriptReference/30_search.html?q=$(CurText)"
```

Now I could select a word, then press shortcut and the reference with the description of the method opens in the browser.

For example online search of word 'Renderer' will bring me here:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/30_search.html?q=Renderer

In my case I will open the help at this URL:
file:///C:/Program%20Files/Unity%20Hub/Documentation/en/ScriptReference/30_search.html?q=Renderer

But I can not find how to set this feature in the Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the extension to achieve this:
[Open in Web](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VCaveman.open-in-web)

You can use keyword **%SELECTION%**, so the URL will be like that:

```
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/30_search.html?q=%SELECTION%
```